# Not able to switch between screens from class component ,every time throwing an error as undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I have the following code for intro slider

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Dimensions,Platform,ScrollView,StyleSheet,View } from 'react-native';
import Button from './Button';
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');
export default class OnboardingScreens extends Component {
  state = this.initState(this.props);

  /*** Initialize the state*/
  initState(props) {

    // Get the total number of slides passed as children
    const total = props.children ? props.children.length || 1 : 0,
      // Current index
      index = total > 1 ? Math.min(props.index, total - 1) : 0,
      // Current offset
      offset = width * index;
    
    const state = {
      total,
      index,
      offset,
      width,
      height,

    };

    this.internals = {
      isScrolling: false,
      offset
    };

    return state;
  }

}


  renderScrollView = pages => {
    return (
      <ScrollView ref={component => { this.scrollView = component; }}
        {...this.props}
        contentContainerStyle={[styles.wrapper, this.props.style]}
        onScrollBeginDrag={this.onScrollBegin}
        onMomentumScrollEnd={this.onScrollEnd}
        onScrollEndDrag={this.onScrollEndDrag}
      >
        {pages.map((page, i) =>
          // Render each slide inside a View
          <View style={[styles.fullScreen, styles.slide]} key={i}>
            {page}
          </View>
        )}
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }

  /**
   * Render pagination indicators
   */
  renderPagination = () => {
    if (this.state.total <= 1) {
      return null;
    }

    const ActiveDot = <View style={[styles.dot, styles.activeDot]} />,
      Dot = <View style={styles.dot} />;

    let dots = [];

    for (let key = 0; key < this.state.total; key++) {
      dots.push(key === this.state.index
        // Active dot
        ? React.cloneElement(ActiveDot, { key })
        // Other dots
        : React.cloneElement(Dot, { key })
      );
    }

    return (
      <View
        pointerEvents="none"
        style={[styles.pagination, styles.fullScreen]}
      >
        {dots}
      </View>
    );
  }


//render buttons


  renderButton = () => {
    const lastScreen = this.state.index === this.state.total - 1;
    
    return (
      <View pointerEvents="box-none" style={[styles.buttonWrapper, styles.fullScreen]}>
        {lastScreen
          // Show this button on the last screen
          // TODO: Add a handler that would send a user to your app after onboarding is complete
          ? <Button text="Next" onPress={() =>this.props.navigation.navigate("Login")} />
          // Or this one otherwise
          : <Button text="Next" onPress={() => this.swipe()} />
        }
      </View>
    );
  }
  
  
 render = ({ children } = this.props) => {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.container, styles.fullScreen]}>
        {/* Render screens */}
        {this.renderScrollView(children)}
        {/* Render pagination */}
        {this.renderPagination()}
        {/* Render Continue or Done button */}
        {this.renderButton()}
      </View>
    );
  }
```

when the last screen reached on click button it should navigate to the Login page but it is throwing an error

```
 TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.navigate')
```

I tried many alternatives and other StackOverflow solution but nothing work

I don't know where I am doing wrong please help or any suggestions?
Thanks in advance

Comment: try [this](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/7961#issuecomment-610025502)
or try to use the reference of `this` in separate variable then use it. like `const ctx = this; ctx.props.navigation.navigate("Login")`.

Comment: Thanks @MohammadABSJabed for replying but this also giving same error

Comment: the link that you refered i used it but  it is showing this error  `Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app` @MohammadABSJabed

Comment: that means you may be using class component, to use this kind of hooks you have to use functional component.