# Data is not rendering using Flatlist in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am fetching data from api and I am storing it in a state in a functional component
if I am simply printing the data in a {data} it is showing all data in json format
but it is not rendering using flatlist.

```js
 
const PlantsBreedScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
}, []);

const fetchData = async() =>
{

    const request =  await axios.get('/obj/Category');
    setData(JSON.stringify(request.data.response.results));
    console.log(request.data.response.results);
    return request;
}

const Item = (props) => (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{props.title}</Text>
    </View>
  );
  
  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <Item cName={item.cName} />
  );
  

return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item._id}
       /> 
    </SafeAreaView>
)
}
    
    
I am getting this data 

[
    {
        "cIcon":"//s3.amazonaws.com/appforest_uf/f1593211075844x987594468971699600/AirPlant.png",
        "cName":"AirPlant",
        "Created Date":"2020-06-12T03:50:32.293Z",
        "Created By":"1589332566210x919673080739546800",
        "Modified Date":"2020-06-26T22:37:58.122Z",
        "_id":"1591933832293x740470401637297400",
        "_type":"custom.category"
    },
    {
        "cIcon":"//s3.amazonaws.com/appforest_uf/f1593211065995x923166783941526000/Aquatic.png",
        "cName":"Aquatic",
        "Created Date":"2020-06-12T03:50:54.814Z",
        "Created By":"1589332566210x919673080739546800",
        "Modified Date":"2020-06-26T22:37:48.282Z",
        "_id":"1591933854814x594601779376298400",
        "_type":"custom.category"
    },
    {
        "cIcon":"//s3.amazonaws.com/appforest_uf/f1593211055775x815245486081858600/CacSucc.png",
        "cName":"CacSucc",
        "Created Date":"2020-06-12T03:51:08.824Z",
        "Created By":"1589332566210x919673080739546800",
        "Modified Date":"2020-06-26T22:37:37.763Z",
        "_id":"1591933868824x824580506688475900",
        "_type":"custom.category"
    },
    {
        "cIcon":"//s3.amazonaws.com/appforest_uf/f1593211046766x525372817880738000/Carnie.png",
        "cName":"Carnie",
        "Created Date":"2020-06-12T03:51:48.497Z",
        "Created By":"1589332566210x919673080739546800",
        "Modified Date":"2020-06-26T22:37:28.878Z",
        "_id":"1591933908497x739290661511488500",
        "_type":"custom.category"
    },
    {
        "cIcon":"//s3.amazonaws.com/appforest_uf/f1593211038814x188848007836712300/Flowery.png",
        "cName":"Flowery",
        "Created Date":"2020-06-12T03:52:02.800Z",
        "Created By":"1589332566210x919673080739546800",
        "Modified Date":"2020-06-26T22:37:20.613Z",
        "_id":"1591933922800x240413248643147620",
        "_type":"custom.category"
    },
    {
        "cIcon":"//s3.amazonaws.com/appforest_uf/f1593211030148x445996690624532700/Leafy.png",
        "cName":"Leafy",
        "Created Date":"2020-06-12T03:52:14.162Z",
        "Created By":"1589332566210x919673080739546800",
        "Modified Date":"2020-06-26T22:37:11.914Z",
        "_id":"1591933934162x408228620159180000",
        "_type":"custom.category"
    },
    {
        "cIcon":"//s3.amazonaws.com/appforest_uf/f1593211021175x413587314607428300/Exotic.png",
        "cName":"Exotic",
        "Created Date":"2020-06-12T03:52:25.027Z",
        "Created By":"1589332566210x919673080739546800",
        "Modified Date":"2020-06-26T22:37:03.554Z",
        "_id":"1591933945027x914059867656276400",
        "_type":"custom.category"
    }
]
```

But I am getting screen with only lines and css style is applied on it but no data is showing
[image]

Please help me how to solve this or any suggestion or alternative to do it
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please refer this link. https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-wind-85sru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are passing `title` as a prop to `Item` in renderItem function,
you have to receive that prop using the same prop name in Item function.

```
const Item = (props) => ( 
    <View style={styles.item}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{props.cName}</Text>
    </View> 
); 
const renderItem = ({ item }) => ( <Item cName={item.cName} /> );
```

Comment: can you please check this code...
[link](https://pastebin.com/VY8j1hn8)

this should work...

Comment: on the basis of your latest updated code just change this line @LRajk

`<Text style={styles.title}>{props.cName}</Text>`

Comment: Thanks @Mohammad ABS Jabed this works for me really very helpfull

Comment: you're welcome.
It's all about passing a prop and receiving that prop with the same name,

Comment: if you don't mind can you please help me in rendering the image also in the same post above @Mohammad

Comment: [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65296021/not-able-to-switch-between-screens-from-class-component-every-time-throwing-an) @MohammadABSJabed can you please help me in this error

Answer (score 2):

You passed the cName as title on Item component.

Please change the item component like below.

```
const Item = (props) => (
  <View style={styles.item}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>{props.title}</Text>
  </View>
);
```

Comment: Then try to modify `item` component: `<Item cName={item.cName} />`.

Comment: @LRajk, have you checked the link which I commented on your question?
If you still can't see changes, please check you fetch data correctly.

Comment: i have updated my code please check this is my complete code @MagicDev

Comment: Try to remove JSON.stringify on setData.

Comment: Still no change @MagicDev

Comment: @LRajk Try to set `extraData={data}` to your FlatList.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better way to handle network requests using React Hooks,

Try extracting your network request to a seperate function and call it inside useEffect.

```
const fetchData = async() =>
{
   
    const request =  await axios.get('https://randomuser.me/api/');
    setData(request.data);
    console.log(data);
    return request;
}



useEffect(() => {
   
  fetchData();
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks @AppCity i considered it but there is not change